# "missing script: build:ssr" error when trying to build server Angular Universal app

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I created simple Angular app and then tried to create a server-side app using Angular Universal. However, in every single tutorial the first step is to run `npm run build:ssr` which in my case throws an error:

`npm ERR! missing script: build:ssr`

I must be missing something obvious but I can't figure out what. I checked StackOverflow for this issue, there is one, however, without accepted answer. One hint would be to check the Angular/Angular Universal version, but these seems to be aligned for me:

```
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@ng-toolkit/universal": "^7.1.2",
    "@nguniversal/common": "^7.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^7.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^7.1.1",
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

this issue is occurring probably because you might not have run the 
@nguniversal express-engine command :

```
 ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject (Project Name)
```

Project name can be found in angular.json file under projects attribute.

This will generate server module and `build:ssr` It should work after running this hopefully.

Comment: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID
I am getting this err. when i run the command.

Answer (score 1):

For better understanding how angular universal should be configured properly you can take a look on official sample universal's starter repo https://github.com/angular/universal-starter

Here you have also example how to setup package.json properly https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/package.json

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have build:ssr script in your package.json file

Comment: No, it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

This error was at me when I was trying ng npm run dev:ssr not in forlder with my Angular project.